# Azure mobile service table filter

Tags: node.js, azure, nodes, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to get users that are present in array onlineUsers, but it is giving me following error. Can someone please give me work around if this doesn't work

CODE:

```
exports.post = function(request, response) {
    var onlineUsers    = ["6990"];    
    // Tables
    var userTable    = request.service.tables.getTable('Users');
    userTable.where(
        function(ou) {
            return ou.search(this.id) != -1;
        },onlineUsers).read({
            success : function(users){
                response.send(statusCodes.OK, { message : users });
            }            
    });
};
```

ERROR:

```
Error in script '/api/test_find.js'. Error: The expression 'ou.search(this.id)'' is not supported.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
userTable.where(function(ou) {
    return this.id in ou;
}, onlineUsers)
```

Keep in mind that the SQL generated contains a separate where clause for each element of `onlineUsers`, so it can become quite inefficient if the array contains many elements. We're looking at improving the query API.